# How do I enter/ find the correct token or error?

Tags: discord.js

I want to create a Discord bot that can remotely start my Minecraft SpigotMC Server, but when I try to run my bot using node bot.js, it outputs an error message,

```
(node:19880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (C:\Users\David\Desktop\Serverstart\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:135:26)
    at Client.login (C:\Users\David\Desktop\Serverstart\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:221:21)
(node:19880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19880) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my package.json code:

```js
{
  "name": "Serverstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bot doing Bot things",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "author": "PalanixYT",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.io": "https://github.com/woor/discord.io/tarball/gateway_v6",
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

And my auth.json:(Don't worry, I already renewed my token)

```js
{
  "token":"NzE3MTI2NDcyMjM3NTgwMjg4.XtWKZw.go81ay5fCu52yyn-xYiK1eIwTzI"
}
```

If I need to give more information, I am more then willing to do so.

Comment: In your main file, what did you have for `client.login(what_did_you_put_here)`?

Comment: Hello, share you code, specifically your `Client.login` function, the error says exactly "an invalid token was provided", you provided a token that doesn't exist.

Comment: um, what file do I have to open?

Comment: The one where you put the login... If you don't know which it means that you haven't coded it yourself, and if that's the case I don't know how we can help...

Comment: I have coded it myself. I just want to know, what file he is talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using this?

```
const config = require('path-to-auth.json');

bot.login(config.token);
```

Comment: in your bot.js file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `config.json` like others have said, but if you push to git, or if you want to use it in actual production you should use `process.env`

file: `.env` (main/root folder)

```
TOKEN=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
```

file: .gitignore

```
.env
```

file: main.js

```js
require("dotenv").config();
bot.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

You will have to download the dotenv module though.
`npm i dotenv`

Depending on which platform you host it on, they might have env variables you can define on the project page like heroku.